# Bootstrap's navigation bar doesn't show up properly inside frameset

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap version3.3.0. This is the code for horizontal navigation bar in bootstrap:

navigation-bars.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The output for above program in mobile devices is 
[image: Not inside frame]
The same program when included in the frame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Frames</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="100%">
   <frame name="left" src="navigation-bars.html" />
   <noframes>
   <body>
      Your browser does not support frames.
   </body>
   </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

shows up like this:
[image: Inside frame]

Please help as to why the frameset and frame is behaving like this and what is the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted is for Bootstrap V4 but you state you're using Bootstrap V3 in your question. You should clarify which version you're using.

Comment: /*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

Comment: You're trying to use code (HTML) from [V4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) with CSS from [V3](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). They aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is due to a rule in .navbar-brand, that is float:left. Using media query to "unable" it solves the problem.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 375px) and (max-width : 788px) { 
       body .navbar-brand{
             float:none;
        } 
 }
```

Comment: Made the float none on a, ul and li tags. This worked. Your answer was the basis. Thank you.